# Advice on managing DLLs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, tfs

I am trying to figure out the best way to handle our dll updates in our company. Previously we had a single code base which was just duplicated per project. It was not fun.

- The new setup has a total of 7 dll's and then the final Unity game.
- 5 of the dll's are stand alone, they have no dependencies.
- 6 depends on the first 5
- 7 depends on the first 6
- Unity project depends on all 7

The issues come up when updating the low level dll's. But lets just assume that we have made a change to #6.

- Make update to #6 locally, test changes, it works
- Merge from Dev branch to Main branch
  *At this point #7 is not aware of the #6 change, we will say that the change wouldnt doesn't effect #7 any way

Should we make a build of #6, update #7(which is getting #6 from a nuget package), Merge #7 to Main, build and then update the game with all needed dll's? Or should we not bother loading #7 with the update from #^ since we know what changed wont effect that project.

**Overall I am just looking for some "How we do it" from some other places that have more veteran experience in how they manage their dll's**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a DLL is internal to the firm but external to the project / solution then we only accept their DLL via nuget.

It's up to the team maintaining an internal dependency to notify dependent projects if they are required to make an update (critical).  This then gets put in the current sprint or scheduled as a waterfall requirement depending on the team style. Otherwise, all inter-team dependencies are deployed via nuget and taken in automatically during the next or current dev cycle depending on team practice.

Full regression will be performed by QA per release anyway so this works pretty well.

So in your case, a change to #6 would not propagate right away unless #6's team deemed it organization critical, in which case all dependent projects would have to update.  #7's team would get this message, update themselves, test, then push out a required update to you.

Comment: Your approach seems to be really organised and clean

Answer (score 2):

This is the approach we are using in our company. We have a local NuGet, every common dll is placed there. Other projects can reference those dlls through NuGet packages. When one of those dlls is updated a new **package is created automatically** and pushed to our local NuGet. The remaining projects that reference that dll are out of date at that moment, so we should update that NuGet package on those projects by hand.

**Automatic update for NuGet packages**:

We use TFS with continuous integration following these steps:

1. One developer modify one of the projects which contains one of those dlls.
2. He/she creates a pull request (PR). A first build runs for compilation and runs the tests.
3. When the PR is approved another build runs for deployment.
4. This second build compiles the solution again and runs the tests again.
5. Then a NuGet Packager step in this build conforms the new package
6. Finally a NuGet Publisher step makes the publication to our local NuGet.

Comment: I have recently setup this exact process to help. I am glad to hear it seems to be on the right track.